# How to derive a custom login-token from a facebook/google/... oauth2 authentication in Spring (Boot) for a single page application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have already set up a running application having:

- an authentication server
- several resource servers
- a javascript-frontend

For the authentication I am using the oauth2-stack of Spring-Security to hand out JWT-tokens to successfully authenticated user's. The login-information is collected in the javascript-fronted which then asks the authentication-server for an auth-token and stores it. This all works well for my application.

What I want to do now is integrate third-party-login-services like Google or Facebook. Currently I am at a point where the process can be started from the javascript-frontend, then the authentication-server does it's magic and communication with the third-party-login-provider. I've gotten so far that the login process is successful and I get the needed information which actually is only the e-mail-address.

But now I'm stuck. I have the authentication information on the server but now I need to construct one of my own authentication-JWT-tokens and hand it to my javascript-frontend. Can anybody give me a hint on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The [JWT Login Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login) in [Spring Security Samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples) demonstrates how to create JWT tokens for your own purposes. The key is to ensure that authentication has already occurred, prior to provisioning said token (which in your example is already the case).

Note that the sample uses the `com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt` dependency as Spring Security already depends on this library internally. You may also consider using `io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api` or another library instead. [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) has a useful list of libraries that support creation of JWTs, and you can filter by Java and click through to the repository to get more information about any of them.

In any case, the sample should be easily adapted to your choice of library, and the out-of-the-box support for verifying JWTs in Spring Security should work.